# Relation between Voltage & frequency in DVS

Tags: voltage, scaling

As per Wiki - "In DVS,  Overvolting is done in order to increase computer performance"

How Overvolting will increase performance??

Also, it says " By applying a higher voltage to the devices in a circuit, the capacitances are charged and discharged more quickly, resulting in faster operation of the circuit and allowing for higher frequency operation."

Aren't the above 2 statements contradiction with for eg DDR2/3/4 where we are decreasing voltage to decrease rise time & further increase performance??

What am I missing!!!

Answer (score 2):

DVS is dynamic voltage scaling.  Increasing the voltage allows the internal capacitances of the wires and transistors to be charged up above the transistor threshold voltages more quickly, allowing the device to operate at a higher frequency.  However, dynamic power consumption in CMOS is proportional to frequency times voltage squared, so you get a 'triple whammy' increase in power consumption.

In DDR2/3/4, the bus is a different animal than the components on the chip.  The data bus is subject to different limitations outside the chip because it is physically much larger.  The spec is designed to use lower voltages for lower power consumption as well as faster transitions.  This is done at design time and the supply voltage and threshold voltages are changed.  In DVS, the threshold voltage is NOT changed, as it cannot be changed without changing the circuit, transistor doping, transistor body biasing, etc.  Since the PCB traces between the RAM chips and the CPU act like transmission lines as opposed to RC limited lines, the performance characteristics are completely different.  The RC time constant does not apply to these traces, so raising the supply voltage does not have the same effect.  Instead, output driver slew rate and supply current are more important.  With a smaller swing, the line can be driven faster and with less power.  On the receive side, amplifiers are required to properly receive the data.

A DDR2/3/4 RAM array can certainly be overclocked with DVS just like any other chip, so long as enough cooling is provided to deal with the extra power dissipation.  However, the interface circuitry may or may not work properly at the higher frequency, even if the supply voltage is increased.

TL;DR: in DVS, the voltage is changed on a fixed CMOS chip.  In DDR2/3/4, the bus is designed to operate at a lower voltage and it is not RC limited like on-chip components.  They cannot really be directly compared.

Comment: I agree with you on the difference between 2 scenarios. but how does this happen :- "Increasing the voltage allows the internal capacitances of the wires and transistors to be charged up above the transistor threshold voltages more quickly,"

Comment: RC[s] consant looking at step change means the time for signal rise at 63% of final voltage, so with higher final voltage the time to reach threshold level is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

What's DVS, kind of overclocking? Elements built for lower voltage operation are faster, because the transition time from low to high state level is shorter compared to the same element with higher nominal voltage. But if you apply higher than nominal voltage to the element this transition time is even shorter, because the threshold level 0,1  remains the same, but the slope is now steeper due to higher supply voltage.
Well, this fact is known and used for gamers, while it is useless for normal operation.

Comment: Slope will be steeper if the freq is increased ryt!!

Comment: @Rishi No, if voltage is increaased.

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, when speaking of DVS, Overvolting is done in order to achieve Overclocking.
First thing, its not always necessary everywhere that Overvolting results in Overclocking.
Secondly, don't confuse the case of DDR2 memories with just the overclocking method. DDR2 are dual-pumped memories, they are not faster just because of Overclocking, principally they are faster because they transfer data on the rising and falling edges of the bus clock signal.